# Apache Camel split JSONArray remove the double quote

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I've split the JSONArray using JsonPathExpression, but the result removed every double quote in each JSON, here is my RouteBuilder.

```
from("timer:scheduler?repeatCount=1")
    .to("http:localhost:8901/rest/getData")
        .split(new JsonPathExpression("$.[*]"))
        .process(new Processor() {
            @java.lang.Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(input);
            }
        })
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Map.class)
    .log("${body}");
```

I just want to unmarshal those JSON using Jackson, but as you might know, Jackson will not parse those JSON without double quote, yes, I might allow Jackson to parse without double quote, but I prefer the JSON to have it. Also it changes the `:` to `=`.

The response from REST call are like this.

```
[
  {
    "v_KDKANWIL": null,
    "v_GJJ": "CRJ"
  },
  {
    "v_KDKANWIL": "002",
    "v_GJJ": "CRJ"
  }
]
```

After splitting and processing it become like this (Just the first JSON).

```
{
  v_KDKANWIL=null,
  v_GJJ=CRJ
}
```

I suspect not just the split, but also in the processor because I set new body using String type.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Ah, stupid me, it should not be a String but Map, so this.

```
String input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

Become this.

```
Map input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`.split()` splits data into java.util.map. Marshal data after split to convert it to JSON using Jackson or Gson. I faced the same issue and adding `marshal()` resolved the issue.

.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.